# Redirect traffic to another page

Tags: nginx

I tried finding a way on StackOverflow with similar posts but I wasn't able to find anything exactly like my problem.

I want to redirect all traffic from subdomain.example.com/ and subdomain.example.com/index.php ( only those paths only, I don't want to affect the rest of the website ) to clientarea.php . I successfully did it for index.php, but wasn't for subdomain.example.com/.

At the moment, my code is only:

```
  location /index.php {

    return 301 /clientarea.php;

  }
```

Comment: Is clientarea.php on the same Webroot? ( subdomain.example.com/clientarea.php )

Comment: @Spirit Yes, it is

Comment: I assume you try to use it as login redirection. If this is the case, I would recommend to solve that via php.

Comment: @Spirit I'm using WHMCS which uses php, but everything is obfuscated. The only things that are not is the HTML code. I'm currently using a HTML redirect code it's so slow to redirect that we have time to see the actual page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will match only `/`:

```
location = / {
    return 301 /clientarea.php;
}
```